# IntelliJ Scala: import works in test folder but not in main folder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an IntelliJ project in scala with the following directory structure (I've renamed files/directories for simplicity):

```
project
|
+--src
|  |
|  +--main
|  |  |
|  |  +--scala
|  |     | 
|  |     +--'X' 
|  |         |
|  |         +--'Y.scala'
|  +--test
|     |
|     +--scala
|        | 
|        +--'X' 
|            |
|            +--'YSuite.scala'
|
+--build.sbt
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm able to import things in the `YSuite.scala` file that I'm not able to in `YSuite.scala` - specifically, the `scala.collections.parallel` packages. I just have no idea how or why I can import in the test file, but not in the parallel application file. I need them in the main file for implementation. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Screenshots are of the `Y.scala` file, `YSuite.scala` file, as well as the `build.sbt` file, if they help at all.

As can be seen, the red text indicates that I wasn't able to import it in `Y.scala` - when I hover over it with my mouse, it simply says `cannot resolve symbol parallel`. However, I've run the test file with some implementation of the parallel package, which runs with no problems.

[Y.scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciAkz.png)

[YSuite.scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuFLh.png)

[build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbvOH.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reload" from SBT tool window? Is it possible to share full project for investigation?

Comment: as y.bedrov said, your build.sbt looks like it's not loaded properly. HEnce all the red there.

Answer (score 0):

a solution that seems to have worked for me:

step 1: *File* -> *Invalidate Caches / Restart*

step 2: build again/spin up sbt